# R reshape table into matrix

Tags: r

I have just started to use R recently.

I have a table like this:

```
(dd <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                  text = "keywords kw1 kw2 kw3 kw4 count 
                  1        a   b   c   d   2
                  2        a   b   d    NA   3
                  3        d   e    NA    NA   2"))

#   keywords kw1 kw2  kw3  kw4 count
# 1        1   a   b    c    d     2
# 2        2   a   b    d <NA>     3
# 3        3   d   e <NA> <NA>     2
```

I want to change it into this:

```
keywords a   b   c   d   e  count 
  1      1   1   1   1   0  2
  2      1   1   0   1   0  3
  3      0   0   0   1   1  2
```

I tried to search it, but didn't find the answer to it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: it's a table `with(dd, ftable(rep(keywords, 4), unlist(dd[, 2:5])))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
df2 <- cbind(dd[1],mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(dd[grep('^kw', 
           names(dd))]))), dd['count'])
row.names(df2) <- NULL
df2
#  keywords a b c d e count
#1        1 1 1 1 1 0     2
#2        2 1 1 0 1 0     3
#3        3 0 0 0 1 1     2
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!! Solved my problem perfectly.